# In Rails , Redirect old url with 'renamed params' to new url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes

My application Old url was (in php)

```
www.abc.com/athlete/?country=2
```

and now new url is (In Rails):

```
www.asdf.com/athletes/?c=2
```

Now, I need to redirect (google crawls) old url to new url. Either via `config/routes.rb`
or via  redirect in controller using redirecting one vertual action to

```
def redirect_to_index
   redirect_to :action => :index, :c => params[:country], :status => 301
end
```

But problem is there are many old urls are without params i.e. no `country`. but on reidrecting I will have `?c=` always.

I don't want to use rough code like

```
def redirect_to_index
   if params[:country]
     redirect_to :action => :index, :c => params[:country], :status => 301
   else
    redirect_to :action => :index, :status => 301
   end
end
```

Any better solution?

Comment: **Best** if `routes.rb` can handle situation like
  `match "/athlete/?country=:country" => redirect("/athlete/?c=:country")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
new_params = {
  :c => params[:country],
  :x => params[:something_else]
}.reject{|k,v| v.nil? }

redirect_to ({ :action => :index, :status => 301 }.merge(new_params))
```